# Syntax error when passing unpacked argument to print in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, argument-unpacking

Instead of a simple debug/log print as this:

```
print "error ", error_number
```

I would like to use a log function that I can expand when required looking something like this:

```
def log(condition, *message):
    if(<do something here...>):
        print(*message)
        <perhaps do something more...>
```

and call it like this:

```
log(condition, "error ", error_number)
```

But I get the following syntax error:

```
print *message
      ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is it a limitation of the print function or is there some way to make it work? If not, is there an equivalent to print that I could use?

I'm using Python 2.7 by the way...

Comment: I added the way to modify your script, without using `__future__` module; see my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`print` is not a function in Python 2.x. In the first snippet you are printing a tuple and the last one has invalid syntax. If you want to use the print function, you need to enable it via `from __future__ import print_function`.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use `__future__`, you can define the logging function like this:

```
def log(condition, *message):
    if(<do something here...>):
        print ' '.join(str(a) for a in message)
        <perhaps do something more...>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `print message` directly, that's enough (it will print the tuple of extra arguments).

---

Little addition to previous answers: in Python 2.x, `print` is not a function but a statement, **but** `print(arg1, arg2)` is valid... as using `print` statement on the tuple `(arg1, arg2)`.

This is a bit different from `print arg1, arg2` as one can see:

```
>>> print 'aaa', 'bbb'
aaa bbb
>>> print('aaa', 'bbb')
('aaa', 'bbb')
```

---

Now, in addition to themel's answer:

**case 1**: not using `*` to expand the argument tuple

```
>>> def p(*args):
...     a(args)  # <== args is a tuple
>>> def a(*args):
...     print args  # <== args is a tuple (but nothing else can be used)
>>> p('bb')
(('bb',),)
```

Result is a tuple of a tuple.

**Case 2**: expanding the arguments in `p`:

```
>>> def p(*args):
...      a(*args)  # <== now arguments are expanding
...
>>> p('bb')
('bb',)
```

Result is a tuple of arguments given to `p`.

So `*args` is correct use, but this is not allowed in a statement.

Comment: Good info that the main issue here is that _print_ is a statement (a funky one), and that statements do not support unpacked arguments (even when they are funky variable argument accepting statements)

Comment: using `print message` directly prints the tuple as "('error ', 22)" instead of "error 22". Tried that before posting, but its not what I wanted.

Comment: Then, question: was your code `print("error ", error_number)` doing what you expect? I would say no, as `print ('error ', 3)` prints `('error ', 3)` and not `error 3` directly. So that's correct, you needed the new version of print.

Comment: My bad, I originally had a lot of `print "error", 3`-like lines in my code (printing what I expected). When I tried to get the log method to work I tried a lot of different syntaxes and the one with parenthesis happened to end up in the question. Q updated.

Answer (score -2):

You just use `*args` to declare the argument tuple, not to access it. See the [example in the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists):

```
def write_multiple_items(file, separator, *args):
    file.write(separator.join(args))
```

The fact that you get a `SyntaxError` should tip you off that this has nothing to do with `print`, anyway.

Comment: @themel No, this is wrong, see my answer: if you do not expand, you get a tuple; if you expand, you get several arguments. This is allowed anywhere. Anyway, your example is correct, as in this case, you need to use the tuple.